# Does Flow work with any JavaScript framework?

Tags: flowtype

Not looking for any recommendations, just an objective assessment if *any* JavaScript framework can be type-checked with Flow in the current state.

With Flow decreasing in popularity compared to TypeScript, framework declaration files tend to be written in TypeScript, and conversion is not trivial nor automatic. Is there still a framework that works well with Flow type inference, or for which you can write your own framework declarations on the fly? Or is Flow mostly used for framework-agnostic business logic today?

Comment: React typings are builtin in Flow

Comment: @AlekseyL. You mean React classes like component etc?

Comment: Can you improve your question with reference to what a framework is? It's quite a loose term. Generally people are referring to view libraries such as react, though react never considers itself a framework. And for example, cypress is a automation test runner calls itself a framework.

Comment: @Brianzchen I was going for application frameworks like React, Vue, Angular and similar. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: I mean all the React building blocks: component classes, hooks, utility functions etc. Anyway think twice before using Flow, because you'll likely need other 3rd parties alongside React

Comment: My company ships a react/redux/styled-components product that is typed throughout using flow, but YMMV. :shrug:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, I think looking into the flow-typed repo and look for a particular lib or framework will answer this. No recent update = no support, unless you have time and interest to make a PR yourself.

https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed

Answer (score 1):

So the main one is react, given that its type defs are built directly into the flow project. The other which I haven't looked into personally is Vue, given that it's written in flowtype. But I cannot confirm how to get their type defs as I haven't used it personally.

But even if a library doesn't ship with type defs, it doesn't mean it doesn't support flow. One clear example is [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/), it's built in flow with first class flow support but do not ship out of the box. Instead their defs are shipped via flow-typed. I'm not sure what their reasoning is, but most likely it's to remove coupling of flow version with styled-component version, and consumers can upgrade each independently.

Overall if you can't find a lib def readily, either not many people use it with flow or the consumers don't bother and just use the types as any. Since there are many projects in the world that don't use any static type checker, having partial static analysis may be good enough.

Comment: Vue 3 is written in TypeScript, AFAIK?

Comment: Yes Vue 3 is written in TypeScript